# PHP/Ajax DataGrid never displays on the page on real webserver, ONLY localhost :(

Tags: php, mysql, database, ajax, datagrid

... But when I upload it to the real server over at winhost.com, the datagrid doesn'r even get displayed on the page!!!! What gives!? EXACT SAME CODE, both running on 2 servers that both support the grid script, but script only works on localhost, and not on real server!? ARGH, Does anyone know what could do this?

Thanks! :)

the code:

Answer (score 1):

Try

- Is configurations files `php.ini` & `httpd.conf` are they same on both servers?
- is permissions are same?
- check log (`apache.log` or `mysql.log`) files to see errors and debug

Comment: Thanks! :) Done. I did not find any issues anywhere. Log files contain no data,, no errors are displayed either.

Comment: @Lucifer, you need to tell me php error code, js error or something

Comment: As already stated, there are **no** errors. It just does not display. If there were errors, I could fix it myself. The table just isn't displaying.